# How to duplicate the Y-axis label of a chart to the other side

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have this chart in Excel with the Y-axis automatically placed on the left side of the chart.

Aside from inserting a textbox, is there any other way to duplicate that label to the other side or to the right side?

Answer (score 1):

Add or remove a secondary axis in a chart in Excel:

- Select a chart to open Chart Tools.
- Select Design -> Change Chart Type.
- Select Combo -> Cluster Column - Line on Secondary Axis.
- Select Secondary Axis for the data series you want to show.
- Select the drop-down arrow and choose Line.
- Select OK.

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score -1):

Simply create a secondary y-axis, ensure it has the same bounds/units as the main y-axis and remove the lines, tickmarks etc. to just leave the labels.

Answer (score -1):

To move the X axis to the right hand side of the chart you can do the following

1. right click on the horizontal axis
2. select format axis
3. select vertical axis crosses at and tick ' maximim value'
4. hit close

hope that helps

Comment: Read the question again. He asked to duplicate, not to move.